# Connected sets in metric space

Tags: real-analysis

A subset $E$ of the real number R<sup>1</sup> is connected if and only if it has the following property : if $x$ and$y$ lies in$E$ and $x<z<y$,then $z$ lies in $E$. 
Is there any similar theorem for R<sup>k</sup> ? What about general metric space ? 
I am aware that a set $E$ is said to be connected if $E$ is not the union of two nonempty separated sets.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated .

Comment: I don't think there are similar theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, I can draw a curve $E$ connecting these two points, but $E$ can contain an arbitrary $(z_1,z_2)$ or not.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The closed topologist's sine curve is a *connected* subset $X$ of $\Bbb R^2$ that is *not path-connected*: that is, there are two points $A$, $B$ in $X$ such that there is no continuous map $$\phi:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$$
such that $$\cases{\phi([0,1])\subset X\\\phi(0)=A\\\phi(1)=B}$$

This seems to make it very difficult to get any kind of generalization of the property you mentioned.

Take $A$ on the $y$-axis, and take $B$ *not* on the $y$-axis.

[image]